# How to get Difference between SelectStartDate to SelectEndDate on monthcalender in C#

Tags: c#

I m trying to get date count from month calender on C# .my code like this

```
leave.Amount = Convert.ToInt32((mclDateRange.SelectionEnd - mclDateRange.SelectionStart).TotalDays.ToString());
```

I got error like this

> *Input string was not in a correct format.*

Answer (score 5):

[TimeSpan.TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property is of type double, you can get the integer part like:

```
leave.Amount = (int) (mclDateRange.SelectionEnd - mclDateRange.SelectionStart).TotalDays;
```

Consider the following example:

```
double d = 123.22d;
int number = Convert.ToInt32(d.ToString());
```

The would result into the exception

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

So in your code, you can leave out the call `ToString` and it would be fine, like:

```
leave.Amount = 
    Convert.ToInt32(
      (mclDateRange.SelectionEnd - mclDateRange.SelectionStart).TotalDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a step by step example on how to diff two datetime objects. Just apply this to your code

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("05/22/2013");

TimeSpan dateDiff = endDate.Subtract(startDate);

int dayDiff = dateDiff.Days;
```

If you want to round fractional days (like 4 days 18 hrs) days to the nearest one (5 in this case) then use TotalDays property and convert to Int.

Answer (score -2):

This is the way i did for datetimepicker hope it will work to monthcalender

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime Todate ,FromDate;
 Todate = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimepicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
            FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimepicker2.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


double datedifference = (Todate - FromDate).TotalDays;
```

Then can check as date checking like this

```
if(datedifference <2)
{
something ..........
}
```

Comment: Why you are converting a `DateTime` object to string and then parsing it again to `DateTime` ?. If you want to consider the `Date` part only then use `datetimepicker1.Value.Date - datetimepicker2.Value.Date)`

Comment: You seriously use this in your software?